# Chaining setTimeouts

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there more efficient, proper way, to write a function like this? The effect I want to achieve is to remove CSS classes in three steps, one after another.

```
function loadColors(){
 setTimeout(()=>{
  document.querySelector('.class-1').classList.remove('class-x')
 }, 0);

 setTimeout(()=>{
  document.querySelector('.class-2').classList.remove('class-z')
 }, 100);

 setTimeout(()=>{
  document.querySelector('.class-3').classList.remove('class-y')
 }, 200);
}
```

Comment: Write a small library?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question looks a bit sketchy and simplified. I suggest that you post a real demo with the three effects that you are trying to achieve — press Ctrl-M in the question editor. The best solution might involve nearly no JavaScript at all.

Comment: Depending on your use case it might make sense to use the css `transition` property to control when your elements change visual state:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: not sure why this is downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the info in an array,then use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to execute.

```
const timeoutPieces = [
    [".class-1", "class-x", 0],
    [".class-2", "class-z", 100],
    [".class-3", "class-y", 200],
];
timeoutPieces.forEach(p => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector(p[0]).classList.remove(p[1])
    }, p[2]);
});
```

If you want to use es6,and have clear name for vairables,use [Array Destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring)

```
timeoutPieces.forEach(([selector, aClass, time]) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector(selector).classList.remove(aClass)
    }, time);
});
```

It's using array,is because the selector,class and timer you used are not likely to have relation,if you are certain the time for timeout is incremental by 100,you can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const addTimer = (piece, index) => [...piece, index * 100];
const timeoutPieces = [
    [".class-1", "class-x"],
    [".class-2", "class-z"],
    [".class-3", "class-y"],
].map(addTimer);

timeoutPieces.forEach(([query, aClass, time]) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector(query).classList.remove(aClass)
    }, time);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## `async` `await` and `promise`

One way to do this is to [use promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction).

`async` functions stop execution each time they encounter an `await` token and "await" the promise (if any) to resolve before continuing. `async` functions are also promises themselves so you can await an async function as well.

## Example

The example uses a timer event to resolve a promise. The function `threeStep` uses the `wait` function to pause execution for the set time.

To show how you can also chain the async function It repeats the 3 steps after the first lot are done by using the async function's returned `promise` to start the second three steps.

```js
const wait = time => new Promise(tick => setTimeout(tick, time));
async function threeStep(time) {
    log(`Step A and wait ${time}ms`);
    await wait(time);
    log(`Step B and wait ${time}ms`);
    await wait(time);
    log(`Step C all done`);      
}

threeStep(2000)
   .then(() => {
      log("Do it again");
      threeStep(1000);  
   });

// a very hacky log function, don't try this at home. :P
function log(data) { logText.innerHTML += data + "<br>" }
```

```html
<div id="logText"></div>
```